# perform client side event on combo box value changed to fill other label

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

i am working on mvc4 project.I have a devexpress combobox.I want to get values in other textbox according to comboxbox value but client side.

I have referring to this example

```
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q360473
```

But i don't know how do i achieve this

here is my partial view code for combobox binding

```
@Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(
    settings => {
        settings.Name = "comboBoxGetUsersByEmail";
        settings.Width = 250;
        settings.SelectedIndex = 0;
        settings.Properties.DropDownWidth = 550;
        settings.Properties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDownList;
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "ManageUsers", Action = "GetEmployeesByEmail" };
        settings.Properties.CallbackPageSize = 20;
        settings.Properties.IncrementalFilteringMode = IncrementalFilteringMode.Contains;
        settings.Properties.TextFormatString = "{0}";
        settings.Properties.ValueField = "email";
        settings.Properties.ValueType = typeof(string);

        settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "function(s, e) { OnEmailChange(); }";

        settings.Properties.Columns.Add("email", "Email", 120);
        settings.Properties.Columns.Add("employeeid", "EmployeeID", 40);
        settings.Properties.Columns.Add("name", "Name", 130);
    }
).BindList(ViewData["Employees"]).GetHtml()
```

Now i want when value of combox changes i have labelfor mvc helper in page so on change of combox value they fill with their vales according

Answer (score 1):

This works fine,
On your javascript function add the following code:

```
<script>

 function OnEmailChange(){
 var selectedValue = comboBoxGetUsersByEmail.GetValue();
 document.getElementById('YOUR_LABEL_ID').innerHTML = selectedValue;
 }
</script>
```